# change is not working with edge browser in angular2

Tags: angular, select, onchange, microsoft-edge

I am working on angular2 in which i have select to sort the search result. on changing the select value i have function which sort the result. it working fine in mozila and chrome but in **edge** it not trigger the event

```
<select name="select" (change)="filterResult()" [(ngModel)]="filter.orderBy">
                    <option value="null">Sort By</option>
                    <option value="price">Price Low to High</option>
                    <option value="price desc">Price High to Low</option>
                    <option value="name">Name</option>
                    <option value="possession">Possession</option>
                    <option value="postedDate">Posted Date</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: There are some known issues with `<select>` and Edge https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5206, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6573

Comment: is there any other way to do this, because  i have to filter the result on the basis of the selected value

Comment: is `filterResult()` not called or is `filter.orderBy` not updated (or the select from `filter.orderBy`?

Comment: Then you need to find an event that is fired by edge when the `<select>` value is changed. I don't know what event Edge fires.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get select working in ng2 is to split the `[(ngModel)]` two-way binding into something like this: `[ngModel]` and use the `(change)` event for emitted events.

```
<select name="select" (change)="filterResult()" [ngModel]="filter.orderBy">
                    <option value="null">Sort By</option>
                    <option value="price">Price Low to High</option>
                    <option value="price desc">Price High to Low</option>
                    <option value="name">Name</option>
                    <option value="possession">Possession</option>
                    <option value="postedDate">Posted Date</option>
</select>
```